# what does this quote mean from great expectations?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> "... "we can no more see to the bottom of the next few hours, than we can see to the bottom of this river what I catches hold of. Nor yet we can’t no more hold their tide than I can hold this. And it’s run through my fingers and gone, you see!"

Answer (score 2):

Its comparing the unpredictability and inevitability of time to that of water.

> we can no more see to the bottom of the next few hours, than we can see to the bottom of this river what I catches hold of

Means that we can't even predict the events of the next few hours, much as you can't see to the bottom of a deep dark river.

> Nor yet we can’t no more hold their tide than I can hold this. And it’s run through my fingers and gone, you see!"

I assume the character takes a handful of water and lets it run out through their finger, to show that trying to stop the flow of time is as foolish and futile as trying to hold onto water.